# Bold Text Within Multi-Line Code In MarkDown (.md) File?

Tags: markdown

I have some code that I want to make bold in `README.md` file. The code is very important and want everyone who reads the README to read it without fail and look good too, by being in a box, at the same time with bold text as well.

But when I try this, only one thing is possible — either multi-line bold or multi-line code. I want it like this:

````
```
**....**
```
````

Please help me out with this.

Comment: The original Markdown does not support markup inside code blocks. Nor do any other flavours of Markdown, to my knowledge.

Comment: You could use inline HTML, if all your tools support it. Or you could highlight the code in some other way, e.g. surround it with comments. Or use some other markup language; I believe it’s doable in ReStructuredText.

Comment: Are you expecting your `README.md` to be rendered and displayed on GitHub (or similar service)? If so, they GitHub's sanitizer will likely strip out any possible solutions. However, if you are rendering it where no such sanitizers restrict things, you have multiple options, most of which would involve using raw HTML (perhaps with some CSS rules).

Comment: @Waylan Yes, I'm Going To Put The `README.md` File In A GitHub Repository. Ok, I Think There Is No Way Of Doing What I Wanted. Thanks For Informing Me @Biffen and @Waylan.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with any flavors of markdown to my knowledge either, however you can use inline markdown like this
`` **`Some text`** ``, which will render as **`Some text`**
instead of
`Some text`

However, this is probably not what you want. If you want to get someone's attention in the multi-line code block, perhaps just write a comment block above it like this:

```py
# ------
# NOTICE: ...
# ------
if 1:
  # ...
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this: `**Some text**`

When you do this **Some text** will be in bold.

This will make the text bold.

Comment: Does this really work within a code block as OP is asking for? I don't think so.